# how many HTTP status codes are there in total?

Tags: http, request, status

Can anyone provide a number for how many HTTP status codes there are? I've seen websites provide a list ~75, but then others say that there are "hundreds".

I'm creating a project around HTTP codes, so it would be helpful to get as a specific a number as possible. Just to get an idea of how many codes I would be working with

I've already checked the following websites, but couldn't get an actual count of the "hundreds" of codes that people allude to. Am I missing something?

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
- https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.1
- https://httpstatuses.com/
- https://www.whoishostingthis.com/resources/http-status-codes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP status codes are in the range from 100 to 599, so there are 500 different ones, by definition. Most of these are not assigned. The actual assignments can be seen at https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml.

Comment: okay that makes sense. So when people say hundreds, they're referring to the hundreds of "possible codes" versus the much smaller number of "assigned codes". hat wasn't clicking before